# Can't replace spaces with horisontal slash to cut the wordpress title with str_replace

Tags: wordpress, replace

i have a wordpress installation and this part of code below:

```
$maintitle = " – ".get_bloginfo( 'name' );
$res = str_replace($maintitle, "", wp_get_document_title());
```

The goal is to cut the title in wordpress, and show the cutted version somewhere on page. So, if my *wp_get_document_title()* returns "Gallery – Some Site" and *get_bloginfo( 'name' )* returnes "Some Site", i expect to see as a result - "Gallery". Of course, it is not only for gallery page, but also for others. But it seems that there is some issue with spaces when i use str_replace. So, it does not replace. Why? I am sure i have "–" in *wp_get_document_title()*, not "-".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dash of wp_get_document_title() is a different charachter.

Try this code somewhere in your page or in a plugin to see the difference:

```
$title = wp_get_document_title();
$bloginfo = get_bloginfo('name');

echo '<div style="padding-left:20rem;"><pre>'; 

var_dump ($title, htmlspecialchars($title));
echo "\n\n";

var_dump ($bloginfo, htmlspecialchars($bloginfo));
echo '</pre></div>';
```

The dash is quite probably &#8211; HTML code, also called &ndash;

So you should use *`&#8211;`* instead of *`-`* in your *str_replace*

Comment: Hi, Pippo, you are right. Yes, there is &#8211; symbol instead of regular "–". Your approach with var_dump helped me to see it with my eyes. Thanks, i voted for your answer.

Comment: @creators Glad to have been of help